# Jquery Preview Video In Div After PHP Validation Not Working While An Image Does

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, video, preview

I use the following code successfully (with different IDs, etc.) to preview a banner image in a div after PHP validates the upload, using AJAX. This works just fine. No issues.

I am having a problem doing the same with a video. The code below works well, except the video doesn't preview. Just echos back the alt tag value. I am passing the uploaded video ID to a hidden input for some back end PHP validation via ajax function. After validation, the video is moved to the folder I want it to move to without a problem. I also echo back an error if the video doesn't meet requirements. This is all good. The video just doesn't show on the page. Any help is appreciated.

---

```
                <div>Upload Video</div>
                <div><input type="file" id="banner-video"></div>
                <div id="loading"></div>
                <div class="padding-top-1" id="show-video"></div>
                <script>
                    $(document).ready(function() {
                        $("#banner-video").change(function() {
                            var data = new FormData();
                            data.append("file", $("#banner-video")[0].files[0]);
                            $.ajax({
                                url: "create-promotions/video-banner-promotions/create-promotion.video.process-banner-video.php",
                                method: "POST",
                                data: data,
                                contentType: false,
                                processData: false,
                                cache: false,
                                beforeSend: function() {
                                    $("#loading").load("../loading.php");
                                },
                                success: function(data) {
                                    $('#loading').hide()
                                    $('#show-video').html(data); // ********** This line seems to be the problem
                                    if ($('#show-video').find('img').length) {
                                        bannerVideo = $('#show-video').html(data);
                                        document.getElementById("the-banner-video").value =
                                            bannerVideo
                                    }
                                }
                            });
                        });
                    });
                </script>
                <input type="hidden" id="the-banner-video" value="">
```

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind. After 3 days of working on it, it was just using the wrong tag on my back end php echo. The code works. Feel free to use it if you ever come across it. Let me know if you would like the other pieces.